# Refresh Bitmap Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, bitmap, firemonkey

I use Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, and I have a `TForm` with a `TImage`.

I load a `PNG` file to `MultiResBitmap` property and set `WrapMode` to `Fit`.

When I run my application and click on a button, I need to change this picture and load a `JPG` file.

I use `Image.Bitmap.LoadFromFile` if the file is on the harddrive or `Image.Bitmap.LoadFromStream` if the JPG file is from a WebService (Get from IdHTTP). Both are on a `Try...Finally` with `Image.BeginUpdate` and `Image.EndUpdate;`

That's ok I see my new picture but the bottom isn't really good, I see a part of the previous picture. I need to move the TForm outside of my screen to see it full.

I try `Image.Repaint` at the end or to Clear the `Bitmap` before load the new file with `Image.Bitmap.Clear(TAlphaColors.White)` but that's change nothing.

Somebody know why ?

**Edit:** I forgot to say that TransparentColor is set on White.

- First:

[image]

- Second:

[image]

- After moving out of screen :

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more please, where exactly you stuck in, and show the code please.

Answer (score 0):

Try without BeginUpdate and EndUpdate.

Comment: Same problem, I forgot to say that TransparentColor is set on White.
First: https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/980373871.png
Second: https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/430373392.png
After moving out of screen : https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/681634273.png

Comment: You are sure to have removed all beginUpdates / Endupdates, even from other components?

Comment: ah yes.. I have a TabControl and when I disable Begin/EndUpdate that's ok, that's strange this code executed right before I change the image ??

Comment: Yes it is strange, because the right is really to use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate, the embarcadero itself says this because it disables temporary the repaint and realignment of the component and its children.  
But after the EndUpdate is not repaint or realignment automatically (I do not know if it's a bug), and I've never been able to simulate this correctly, even giving repaint, especially when it or it children need to be realigned.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it as:

```
Image1.MultiResBitmap[0].Bitmap.LoadFromFile('Location\Image.jpg');
```